# Electricity#breakerbox

Tags: electrical

My neighbor came home to find the pier company turned her off. It was raining and she was wet trying to figure out what happened, she said she was going to try and reset the breaker but when she did she got k ocked unconscious by electricity. How could this happen when the power company turned off her power.

Comment: Something is *seriously* wrong with her house.  Do you know why she got cut off?

Comment: Forgot to pay the bill.paid the bill by phone that night from the ER and they turned it back on the next day.

Answer (score 2):

### The power company didn't turn her off.  Something broke.

What has happened is that the supply wires from the power company have taken damage.  This is a "call the power company" thing.

Given that this is a safety and technical thing, the line electricians who come out to fix it *will not care at all* about your billing status. And won't even mention it.

Separately from that issue, there are very serious defects in your house's grounding electrode system, that may have existed for awhile. Those also need to be addressed ASAP so your panel stops trying to kill you.  That, however, is on you.

The power line defect is combining with the grounding defect to make your panel dangerous. Don't go near it, and warn off the linemen too.